# How to change color of text in windows form when you click a button?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I click a button with a word e.g "cat" I want this word in richTextBox1 change to color red. Of course I made it wrong, but I would like to learn how to change it.

```
  private void btn1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        string wordToColor = button.Text;
        ChangeColorOfText(richTextBox1, wordToColor);
    }

    private void ChangeColorOfText(RichTextBox richTextBox1, string word)
    {
        ColorDialog colorDialog1 = new ColorDialog();
        colorDialog1.Red = richTextBox1.SelectionColor;
        int index;
        do
        {
            index = richTextBox1.Find(word);
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(index, word.Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = ColorDialog.Red;
            }
        }
        while (index >= 0);
    }
```

Comment: One thing I notice is that you're not supplying the `index` to the `Find()` method, so if the word occurs in the text, the program will be stuck in a loop that finds the first occurrence time and time again. You might want to include details about the current behavior in your question - some people might want to help but don't have time to copy your code into a program just to find out what your question is about.

Comment: What spesific thing doesn't work for you?

Comment: You see that you create a ColorDialog but never show it, then assign a RichTextBox.SelectionColor to *something*, then try to re-assign the property using `ColorDialog.Red` (?) Have you tries to use `colorDialog1.ShowDialog()` and get the Color the User picked when the dialog closes?

Answer (score 0):

I had few things that may be a solution for you:

1. It was a problem for me but it's not a must:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            //Your code for finding and selecting your text
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myRichTextBox.Text))
            {
                //Your code for selecting your text
                myRichTextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
                myRichTextBox.SelectionLength = myRichTextBox.Text.Length;
            }

            myRichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            myRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

I think your problem was not setting the font before you set the color

(When I added the line `myRichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);` everything worked)

2. The Second thing I did in the code was to use

`myRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;`

insted of

`richTextBox1.SelectionColor = ColorDialog.Red;`

it's easier and more efficient.

3. At the line

`private void ChangeColorOfText(RichTextBox richTextBox1, string word)`

you dont have to add the `RichTextBox richTextBox1` element. (worked fine for me without it).

Comment: The Font has nothing to do with the SelectionColor.

Comment: ```richTexBox1``` in your code is the same as ```myRichTexBox``` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `ColorDialog colorDialog1 = new ColorDialog();
        colorDialog1.Red = richTextBox1.SelectionColor;` 
and changed `richTextBox1.SelectionColor = ColorDialog.Red; to`richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
I thought it will work but just when I write the same word in the text box that is in the button and click on the button the form freezes.

Comment: You've put the `Find()` method in a loop, so that you can find multiple occurrences of the word. But it keeps finding the first occurrence because you're not supplying the parameter that specifies the offset where to start the search from. That's why the application freezes.